# What is the best way to wait that an administrator validate something before comitting it?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a web application where several groups have their own page but if they want to modify it, an administrator has to validate it before.
For example, can change to change its logo, post new photo, change their phone number, their name, their location etc... Basically they can edit a value in the database but only if the administrator accepts it. The administrator has to validate every modification because... our customer asked us to.

That's why we have to create a system that could be called "*pending queries*" management.

At the beginning I thought that keeping the query in the database and executing when an administrator validate it was a good idea, but if we choose this option we can't use PDO to build prepared statements since we have to concatenate string to build our own statement, wich obvious security issues.

Then we thought that we should keep PHP code that calls the right methods (that use PDO)  in our database and that we will execute with `eval()` when the administrator validates it. But again, it seems that using `eval()` is a very bad idea. As says this Rasmus Lerford's quote : *"If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the
wrong question"*.

I thought about using eval because I want to call methods that uses PDO to deal with the database.

So, what is the best way to solve this problem ? It seems that there is no  safe way to implements it.

Comment: your letting people you dont trust edit php on a website?

Comment: @nogad, they won't exactly edit php, we will just call method with the string they filled in a form. But since the php code isn't executed directly we have to store it somewhere somehow. Is my question obscure ?

Comment: yes it is. what's the "string" they filled in a form?

Comment: For example, if the group wants to change its logo, it will be the URL of the logo. There is a lot of different case, they can post new photo, change their phone number, their name, their location etc... Basically it will be the new value of a field in the database.

Comment: I think you need to give us some examples. Update your question... (not in the comments).

Comment: Looks like you need a CMS.

Comment: im not seeing any code so why `eval()` is even mentioned is confusing

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i think he is building a CMS

Comment: Why would someone changing a URL to a logo, or changing their contact details require `eval()` and execute random PHP? I think you have a design flaw somewhere. This is usually handled by a form that posts values which you put in a database.

Comment: ^ why would the even require human *validation* at all?

Comment: I find it very unlikely that it's literally impossible to find a way to prepare the query you want to execute.

Comment: I find it very unlikely as well, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: Just build the functionality into your system that will allow your users to do what you allow them to do. Not sure why you even have something like "pending queries". Is that actual php code, or database code? What happens if you approve such a query? Does your system execute said query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible approach, with an attempt to keep the things organised to an extent, as the system begins to scale:

- Create a table called `PendingRequests`. This will have to have most of the following fields and maybe quite a few more:

  ```
  (id, request_type, request_contents, reqeust_made_by, request_made_timestamp, 
       request_approved_by, request_approved_timestamp, ....)
  ```
- `Request_contents` is a broad term and it may not just be confined to one column alone. How you gather the data for this column will depend on the front-end environment you provide to the users (WYSIWYG, etc).
- `Request_approved_by` will be `NULL` when the data is first inserted in the table (i.e. user has made an initial request). This way, you'll know which requests to present in the administration panel. Once an admin approves it, this column will be updated to reflect the `id` of the admin that approved it and the approved changes could eventually *go live*.
- So far, we've only talked about managing the requests. Once that process is established, then the next question would be to determine how to finally map the approved requests to `users`. As such, it'd actually require a bit of study of the currently proposed system and its workflow. Though, in short, there may be two school of thoughts:

  - **Method 1:**
    Create a new table each for everything (logo, phone number, name, etc) that is customisable. 
                    Or
  - **Method 2:**
    Simply add them as columns in one of your tables (which would essentially be in a 1:1 relationship with the `user` table, as far as attributes such as logo, name, etc. are concerned).
- This brings us to `Request_type`. This is the field that will hold values / flags for the system to determine which field or table (depending on *Method 1* or *Method 2*) the changes will be incident upon - after an admin has approved the changes.
- No matter what requirement or approach it is to go about database management, PHP and PDO are both flexible enough to help write customisable and secure queries.
- As an aside, it might be a good idea to maintain a table for history of all the changes / updates made. By now, it should probably be apparent that the number of history tables will once again depend on *Method 1* or *Method 2*.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

Both your ideas are, to be frank, simply weird.

Add a field in a table to tell an approved content from unapproved one.

Comment: That might be a solution but that really makes us change all our already wrote php. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That makes you drop all the unnecessary PHP and add a single field. Delete a metric ton of code and replace it with 1 field. That option really **should** sound good to you.